Store numbers as "random" seed
Is it possible to calculate a seed from a given list of numbers, such that this seed will cause a number-generating function (like rand()) to output this list of numbers?
And, at which point does it become unlikely that such a seed can be found at all (if the input list gets too large, for example)?
It doesn't have to be rand(), of course. Any generating function would do, and would be known at the time of the calculation.
For example:
int seed;
int myRand() // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    seed = seed*1103515245 + 12345;
    return (seed/65536) % 32768;
}

// given numbers: 19098, -31546, 32637, 21910, -27300
// use black magic maths to find seed 75235

int main() {
    
    seed = 75235;
    
    printf("%d\n", myRand()); // 19098
    printf("%d\n", myRand()); // -31546
    printf("%d\n", myRand()); // 32637
    printf("%d\n", myRand()); // 21910
    printf("%d\n", myRand()); // -27300

    return 0;
}


Thanks!

Did I answer wrong question? Would be glad to hear any statements

For Linear Congruential Generator, which, I believe, rand() is of typical implementation, it is rather easy. Knowing parameters, you compute modular inverse and invert the formula. Not knowing your platform, here is simple example
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t m = 0xd1342543de82ef95ULL; // parameters from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
uint64_t c = 0x1ULL;

uint64_t im = 6281218453581128637ULL; // modular inverse from m using Mathematica ModularInverse[m, 2^64]

uint64_t lcg(uint64_t xi) { // direct LCG
    return m*xi + c;
}

 uint64_t ilcg(uint64_t xp) { // inverse LCG, such that ilcq(lcg(q)) == q
    return (xp - c)*im;
}

int main() {
    
    uint64_t idx = 987610342345234534ULL;
    
    printf( "LCG is %llu\n", lcg(idx) );
    printf( "INV is %llu\n", ilcg(lcg(135797531ULL)) );

    return 0;
}

If you don't know how your rand() is implemented but still sure this is LCG, this would be more complex, see here for an example, or there

I interpreted the question completely differently than you apparently did. It sounds to me like OP is asking if you can find a seed value to produce any arbitrary list of values, rather than whether you can reverse engineer the seed that generated the LCG’s observed output sequence.

@pjs Rereading the question, you are likely right. I remove the answer as soon as OP answers. Thank you

Hey, thanks for the answer - pjs is right, however.
